# Create a function that tidies up any text in r

Tags: r

i am new to r and trying to create a regular expression that abbreviates any word over 5 letters in the input vector (e.g hungry would become hungr.). At the moment i am using gsub, but it  is removing the first 5 letters of words over five letters rather than following letters.

current code:

```
gsub(pattern = "[a-z]{5}", replacement =  ".", x = text_converter)
```

Comment: this is a regular expression in a bigger function

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: `abbreviate("hunger", minlength = 5)`

Comment: hi, you should include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that everybody can just copy paste the code you provide and be at the same step as you are. You can use ```dput``` to generate the code needed for your data, or use a dataset automatically included in R (```iris``` or ```mtcars``` for example)

Comment: @d.b gave the most appropriate solution, but if you want to know how to do it in regex, it's `gsub("([a-zA-Z]{5}).*","\\1", text)`. This will retain the first five letter characters (upper or lower case) and discard whatever came after.

Comment: somebody post an answer from these comments please ...

Comment: so if my input is for example: text <- "the very reliable dog jumped over the fences", i would like the output to be "the very relia. dog jumpe. over the fence."      gsub("([a-zA-Z]{5}).*","\\1", text) works great but only for the first word? thanks

Answer (score 0):

So here is the edited version after you added your explanation in the comment section:
We need the following function:

1. Your string is "the very reliable dog jumped over the fences"
2. strsplit splits this string whenever there is a space in the string and gives you a list of those words

   ```
    [[1]]
      [1] "the"      "very"     "reliable" "dog"      "jumped"   "over"     "the"      "fences"
   ```
3. lapply applys the function, gsub("([a-zA-Z]{5}).*","\1", x), to each word in  the list from step 2, which reduces the letters in each word to 5 or less.

   ```
    [[1]]
     [1] "the"   "very"  "relia" "dog"   "jumpe" "over"  "the"   "fence"
   ```
4. finally paste with collapse, concatenates the vector of strings from step 3 to a string and the split_reduce function returns this string as the final output.

   ```
     [1] "the very relia dog jumpe over the fence"
   ```

So here is the function:

```
split_reduce <- function(text){ 
                    text<-strsplit(text, " ") 
                    text_reduced <- lapply(text,function(x)gsub("([a-zA-Z]{5}).*","\\1", x))
                    paste(unlist(text_reduced), collapse = ' ')
                    }    
split_reduce("the very reliable dog jumped over the fences")
 #[1] "the very relia dog jumpe over the fence"
```

Comment: Add some details around your answer.

Comment: so if my input is for example: text <- "the very reliable dog jumped over the fences", i would like the output to be "the very relia. dog jumpe. over the fence." gsub("([a-zA-Z]{5}).*","\\1", text) works great but only for the first 5 letter word? thanks